# sleep 0 has special meaning?

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, sleep

I'm seeing a lot of usages of `sleep 0` in my one of my client project.

The code look something like this.

```
while true 
  ...
  ...
  sleep 0
end
```

Reading through some of the answer of SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727420/significance-of-sleep0) it seems that `sleep 0` has some significance.

What I want to known now is that does scheduling for other thread to run (if they are waiting to run) during the time slice `0` is a job of a lang VM like ruby or python or it is a job of kernel.

In order word does Ruby VM would honor `sleep 0` like it is mention in the above link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, for a couple of reasons, first of all, (mri) ruby threads are wrappers around native threads with an additional GVL lock.

Essentially what ruby is doing when you call sleep is calling the underlying, native, platform dependent sleep and releasing the GVL so that other running threads can acquire it. So `sleep(0)` is both yielding to other native threads that may be waiting to be executed as well as releasing the current thread's hold on the GVL which would otherwise keep the Ruby VM from executing.

Here's a quick rundown of how you can see this from mri source:

1. We get the definition of Kernel sleep from https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/process.c#L7542, which we see is implemented in c in the function `rb_f_sleep`
2. Next we go to `rb_f_sleep` and see that in the case of a single argument it calls [`rb_thread_wait_for`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/process.c#L4379)
3. Going to the `rb_thread_wait_for` definition we see a call to [`sleep_timeval`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/thread.c#L1172)
4. `sleep_timeval` has a call to [`native_sleep`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/thread.c#L1111)
5. `native_sleep` is platform dependent and implemented in thread_pthread.c and thread_win32.c for posix and windows systems respectively. In either case we see calls to `GVL_UNLOCK_BEGIN` [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/thread_pthread.c#L1130) and [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/thread_win32.c#L307)

**EDIT**

To be more precise:

*Windows:*

The windows implementation of `native_sleep` uses `WaitForMultipleObjects` which does indeed yield the remaining time slice, see: [Does WaitForSingleObject give up a thread's time slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170272/does-waitforsingleobject-give-up-a-threads-time-slice)

*Posix:*

The posix implementation uses `pthread_cond_timedwait`, which blocks the currently running thread.

Either way, the main thing to note here is that Ruby threads use the underlying thread blocking mechanisms of the OS and release the GVL with any call to sleep, allowing other threads to take control.

Comment: Just to clarify, that being said, it's unlikely that the person writing that block of code was really trying to do what I described, so I kind of highly doubt whether or not those sleep calls would actually be useful. In fact, any time there is ruby application code with a call to sleep in it I'd be very likely to say that it's a code smell (though not all the time).

Comment: Great answer. Are you familiar with the [Ruby Cross Reference](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/ident?i=rb_f_sleep)? It's a pretty great way to explore the MRI source.

Comment: @Jordan: awesome resource, looks pretty similar to LXR, thanks for the info!

Comment: Yep, it's generated by LXR!

Comment: @Jordan: Ha, just saw the `This page was automatically generated by the 0.9.9 LXR engine.` :)